# Is there a Python Function for building a average Price which takes 2 arrays as arguments

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, arraylist

first of all i'm absolutely new to Python and try to learn this by myself. I got the following exercise to practice and try to solve it with `NumPy` and `Pandas`.

Share trades are recorded using 2 arrays. The name of the share being traded goes into the first array. The share price of the trade goes into the same position of the second array.
For instance the arrays might look like this:

```
String[] shares = {"HSBC","o2","Vodafone","Vodafone","HSBC","o2","Vodafone"};
double[] prices = {6.40,9.99,2.40,2.45,6.37,10.10,2.50};
```

I need to write a method called `averagePrices` which takes the 2 arrays as arguments. The method should print out the average share price for each company rounded to 2 decimal places. The arrays above would produce:

```
Vodafone: £2.45
HSBC: £6.39
o2: £10.05
```

Using simply `Lists` and `For` loops i get the right results, but i want to handle this problem as if the lists would be longer and not handy enough to type all positions of the single values step by step on my own. 
So i am looking for a function like a `VLookup` in Excel or something similar using `pandas`, which can sum up the corresponding prices for different the shares to build the average.

```py
import numpy as np

shares = np.array(["HSBC", "o2", "Vodafone", "Vodafone", "HSBC", "o2", "Vodafone"])
prices = np.array([6.40, 9.99, 2.40, 2.45, 6.37, 10.10, 2.50])

HSBC_bool = shares == "HSBC"
o2_bool = shares == "o2"
Vodafone_bool = shares == "Vodafone"

HSBC = shares[HSBC_bool]
o2 = shares[o2_bool]
Vodafone = shares[Vodafone_bool]

HSBC_count = HSBC.shape
o2_count = o2.shape
Vodafone_count = Vodafone.shape

HSBC_share = []
o2_share = []
Vodafone_share = []

if HSBC_bool.any == True:
    HSBC_share.append(prices[:])

if o2_bool.any == True:
    o2_share.append(prices[:])

if Vodafone_bool.any == True:
    Vodafone_share.append(prices[:])

print(Vodafone_share)
print(o2_share)
print(HSBC_share)


avg_HSBC = sum(HSBC_share) / HSBC_count
avg_o2 = sum(o2_share) / o2_count
avg_Vodafone = sum(Vodafone_share) / Vodafone_count

print(round(avg_HSBC, 2))
print(round(avg_o2, 2))
print(round(avg_Vodafone, 2))
```

Comment: If you are able to use pandas, simply use `pd.DataFrame({'shares': shares, 'prices': prices}).groupby('shares').mean()` . See answer from ibarrond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `pandas` and the`groupby().mean()` function. I suggest you to read online and play with it some time before asking in SO, otherwise you won't learn that much.

Link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html

In your case:

```
shares = np.array(["HSBC", "o2", "Vodafone", "Vodafone", "HSBC", "o2", "Vodafone"])
prices = np.array([6.40, 9.99, 2.40, 2.45, 6.37, 10.10, 2.50])

df = pd.DataFrame({'shares': shares,
                   'prices': prices})

df.groupby('shares').mean()
```

Which results in:

```
          prices
shares
HSBC       6.385
Vodafone   2.450
o2        10.045
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate on the different names using the np.unique function. Then use the np.argwhere to compute the corresponding average.

Here is a working example :

```
shares = np.array(["HSBC", "o2", "Vodafone", "Vodafone", "HSBC", "o2", "Vodafone"])
prices = np.array([6.40, 9.99, 2.40, 2.45, 6.37, 10.10, 2.50])

def Average_price(shares, prices):
    average_price={}
    for share in np.unique(shares):
        value = 0
        for indice in np.argwhere(shares == share):
            value += prices[indice]
        average_price[share] = value / len(np.argwhere(shares == "HSBC"))
    return average_price

average_price = Average_price(shares, prices)
In [1] : print(average_price)
Out[1] : {'HSBC': array([ 6.385]), 'Vodafone': array([ 2.450]), 'o2': array([10.045])}
```

Answer (score 0):

a tricky way would be to compute the count and than divide the price by that count and compute the sum and create your final dictionary :)

No packages needed by the way

```py
shares = ["HSBC", "o2", "Vodafone", "Vodafone", "HSBC", "o2", "Vodafone"]
prices = [6.40, 9.99, 2.40, 2.45, 6.37, 10.10, 2.50]

# Get unique shares 
unique_shares = list(set(shares))
# Get count of shares
count_shares = [shares.count(x) for x in shares]
# Get average price with corresponding share
avg_shares = [round(x/y, 2) for x, y in zip(prices, count_shares)]
# Zip result into single list of tuple
avg_prices_per_share = list(zip(shares, avg_shares))
# Get average based on count of shares and computed averaprice for each share
result  = {unique_key: round(sum(v for k, v in avg_prices_per_share if k==unique_key), 2)
    for unique_key in unique_shares}
```

Output :

```
{'HSBC': 6.39, 'Vodafone': 2.45, 'o2': 10.05}
```